# C# WPF: делегат не изменяет DataGrid переданную по ссылке

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть WPF приложение, котором есть MyDataGrid. У нее есть обработчик события `MyDataGrid_Loaded`. В этом обработчике я делаю некие действия, например `MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh()`. Для уменьшения задержки при загрузке датагрида я объявил делегат и обновляю датагрид в нем, причем передаю ему `MyDataGrid` по ссылке:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public delegate void DataGridUpdateDelegate(ref DataGrid datagrid);

    public static void DataGridUpdate(ref DataGrid datagrid)
    {
       datagrid.Items.Refresh();
    }

    private void MyDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ...
       DataGridUpdateDelegate _tmpDelegate = DataGridUpdate;
       _tmpDelegate.BeginInvoke(ref MyDataGrid, nul, null);
    }
}
```

Но `MyDataGrid` не обновляется, хотя делегат отрабатывает.

Что тут не так?

Comment: А какого типа переменная `MyDataGrid` мы должны догадаться сами?

Comment: @VladD ну какого оно типа понятно. скорее всего это имя контрола. Просто интересно как это компилируется без указания типа переменной после слова ref в обьявлении делегата и метода

Comment: Пардон, ее тип DataGrid

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, если я напишу «у меня не компилируется `myLeftToe + dirtyShoesOfMyCousin`», это будет настолько же понятно. Указывая переменную, надо бы указывать и её тип.

Comment: @AVM: Окей, уже лучше. Это переменная или поле в классе? В каком? И откуда должны взяться данные в вашем контроле, как вы их туда передаёте? Этого всего в вопросе нет покамест.

Comment: Пост обновил. Есть еще XAML, там определена MyDataGrid.

Comment: Просто спрошу, интересно. Зачем в данном случае используется ref? Если мне память не изменяет он нужен только если требуется менять саму ссылку, а не данные по ней (это и без ref можно).

Comment: я не поинмаю зачем передавать его по ref. и  BeginInvoke насколько я помню с древних времен асинхронности выполняется в потоках пула, а не UI, то есть он должен ругаться на то что не в том потоке, а исключение проглатывается

Comment: я пробовал из без ref, все равно результат тот же. С ref я экспериментировал

Comment: Попробуй так.
MyDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { //MyDataGrid changing... } ));

Comment: Вот так тоже пробовал - работает, только не заметил выигрыша в быстродействии... Ладно, думаю хватит тут экспериментировать )

Comment: @AVM: А причём тут быстродействие? Проблема ведь в корректности работы? Вы бы точно проверили, исполняется ли код делегата. Сдаётся мне, что вы посылаете его на thread pool, а оттуда работать с контролами просто нельзя.

Comment: @Vlad ну значит моя догадка верна, что в пуле оно работает. странно что приложение не падает. хотя помню в  4.5 вроде поменяли поведение unhandled исключений. вот только не помню в какую сторону

Comment: @vitidev: [Ага.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) По крайней мере, _не_ в главном потоке. // А unhandled exception перестали убивать процесс, кажется, только в `Task`'ах.

Comment: ОК, господа, спасибо, только обсуждение куда-то не туда отклонилось... кажется.  Вы вроде поняли суть вопроса. Быстродействие при том же самом, что мне нужна и корректность работы и быстродействие, иначе мне не было бы смысла так экспериментировать.

Comment: @AVM: А что тут обсуждать? Данных недостаточно. Что для вас быстродействие? Если у вас важно быстро показать UI, то отложить загрузку через `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (именно `Dispatcher`) — правильный ход. А если тормозит загрузка данных, то в ней и проблема: куда вы её не выгружайте, `Items.Refresh` всё равно должно бежать в UI-потоке, и если эта операция занимает 10 секунд (например, если вы почему-то напрямую подключили базу данных к `DataGrid`, и `Refresh` читает из неё), то это так и есть, и все это 10 секунд UI будет висеть. Вы ж не даёте ваш источник данных, чтобы стало понятно, в чём...

Comment: @AVM: ... проблема. Если вы и правда грузить данные в UI-потоке, это неправильно, их надо грузить в фоновом потоке в VM, и привязывать UI к VM, а не к модели. Но это мои догадки на пустом месте, потому что у вас в вопросе _нет информации_ о том, что же именно происходит медленно.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, в каком потоке выполняется работа с элементом DataGrid. 
В GUI WPF может существовать только один поток управляющий основным окном и он должен быть главным, тот с которого начался процесс.